# select one value of checkboxCombobox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, combobox, checkbox

i am using several [checkboxcomboboxes](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/extending_combobox.aspx). for my sollution one of these boxes needs to behave as a combobox in a specific situation. i need to select one value only. i tried the following:

```
    private void PreDefSerials_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!one_select)
            return;
        else
        {
            // set selected value
            if (PreDefSerials.SelectedIndex != 0)
            PreDefSerials.CheckBoxItems[PreDefSerials.SelectedIndex].CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
            return;
        }
    }
```

EDTI:

how can i set all the checkstateds of the items to not-selected and aftwerwards make the checkstate of the latest selected value to selected?

Comment: you mean to say, event not firing? or you are getting some error in the said event? or what? please make it clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that control, so I *might* not have all of the syntax correct, but I think you can try looping through your items and "unchecking" anything that was checked.  Also, you would have to turn "off" the event for the time being or else this event would probably keep firing on every "uncheck":

```
private void PreDefSerials_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!one_select)
    return;
  else
  {
    if (PreDefSerials.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
      //only uncheck items if the current item was checked:
      if (PreDefSerials.CheckBoxItems[PreDefSerials.SelectedIndex].CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
      {
        // stop firing event for now:
        PreDefSerials.SelectedValueChanged -= PreDefSerials_SelectedValueChanged;

        for (int i = 0; i < PreDefSerials.CheckBoxItems.Count; i++)
        {
          if (i != PreDefSerials.SelectedIndex)
          {
            PreDefSerials.CheckBoxItems[i].CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
          }
        }

        // wire event again:
        PreDefSerials.SelectedValueChanged += PreDefSerials_SelectedValueChanged;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This assumes that when you check an item, it will get checked and fire this event.  This code just goes through the list and then "unchecks" everything else.  Refactor as needed.

Comment: looks nice, but i get an error with this part of code:

     PreDefSerials -= PreDefSerials_SelectedValueChanged;

Error 5 Cannot convert method group 'PreDefSerials_SelectedValueChanged' to non-delegate type 'PresentationControls.CheckBoxComboBox'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: @Moonlight whoops, updated code.  I forgot to add the actual "event" you should be sub\unsubscribing to.

Comment: this is not the actual answer for my question but it is a great kick in the right direction, i will build further on this (if i get i right i will post an answer myself)

Comment: @Moonlight The post was a little confusing between "CheckState" and "Selected".  It *seemed* to make more sense to handle the "check" issue, but I'm guessing this code is easily changed to "unselect" items, too.