# select one value of checkboxCombobox(additional)

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, checkbox

this is an additional question of [select one value of checkboxCombobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533858/select-one-value-of-checkboxcombobox)

i needed for a particular situation a checkbox-combobox with actions like a regular combobox. i needed to be able to select only one value at a time. i got that figured out now. my next problem is:

```
private void PreDefSerials_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (PreDefSerials.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        // shut down the evenhandler
        PreDefSerials.SelectedValueChanged -= PreDefSerials_SelectedValueChanged;
        // get the selected items name.
        string test = PreDefSerials.SelectedItem.ToString();

        // deselect all boxes
        for (int i = 0; i < PreDefSerials.CheckBoxItems.Count; i++)
        {
            PreDefSerials.CheckBoxItems[i].CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
        }

        if(test != "")
            // select the selected text again
            PreDefSerials.CheckBoxItems[test].CheckState = CheckState.Checked;

        // reinstate the eventhandler
        PreDefSerials.SelectedValueChanged += PreDefSerials_SelectedValueChanged;
    }
}
```

my problem now is that when I select a second item in the checkbocombobox the selected item is (item1, item2). with this name my recheck of the item is not working.

how can I get only the recent clicked item of a checkboxcombobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do i always want to do it the hard way! why try to use a checkboxcombobox as combobox? just because i have it on my form alreaddy!.

there is a better and way more easy way to accomplish this problem! add a combobox. so i did. my new solution is an invisible combobox on the same spot as the checkboxcombobox. when a certain event occurs my combobox will be made visible and my checkboxcombobox will be made invisible.

```
comboBox1.Visible = true;
PreDefSerials.Visible = false;
```

and the combobox will disapear again when my actions are done. everyone thanks for thinking with me.

Answer (score 0):

The property `SelectedItem` contains the recent selected item, the property `SelectedItems` contains all selected items.

Comment: string test = PreDefSerials.SelectedItem.ToString();
also fills the string with (item1,item2)